# How make a timetable given data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a school timetable and I'm getting the data from another site and my data looks like this:

```
{
  "subject": "Maths",
  "day": "1",
  "period": "2"
},
...
```

What would the best way to make a HTML table using JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess the CSS grid would be a solution for this. Something like this:

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.row{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
align-items: center;
justify-items:center;
}
.info{
border: solid 1px #ddd;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="info">Period</div>
    <div class="info">Mo</div>
    <div class="info">Tue</div>
    <div class="info">We</div>
    <div class="info">Tu</div>
    <div class="info">Fr</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="info">1</div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
   </div>
      <div class="row">
    <div class="info">2</div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info">Math</div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
   </div>
      <div class="row">
    <div class="info">3</div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
   </div>
         <div class="row">
    <div class="info">4</div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope this works.

The Javascript is fairly easy:

You add the info items an id like so: `<div id="r1c1" class="info">1</div>`
And you can than: `document.getElementById("r1c1").innerText = "Your class"`

If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: I edited the question because I didn't clarify how I want the table to look like.

Comment: Gimme a minute. ;)

Comment: Why not just use the standard `<table>` markup instead of your overcomplicated solution? I don't see any benefits

Comment: I think the grid is more sophisticated, then regular tables. I usually use it instead of tables.

Comment: I'm not sure about the accessibility aspects, and about implementing cases with `rowspan` or `colspan`  (Which comes out of the box when you use the regular elements). There's also the support for old browsers (The dreadful IE)

Comment: Can you go in more details? I'm not that big of an expert... 

Comment: Neither do I, I was just sharing my thoughts with you :)